# Multiple threads inside class accessing data

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I've read that different threads share the same memory segments apart from the stack. There is something i've been trying to understand. I have a class which creates different threads. Below is a simple example of what I am doing, creating one thread in the constructor.

When an object of this class is created, in main() for example, all the threads can access the same member variables. If every thread gets its own stack, why doesn't each thread get a copy of the member variables rather than access to the same variable. I have looked around and I'm trying to get a picture in my mind of what is going on in memory here with the different stack frames. Many thanks in advance for any replies.

```
////////////////////////    
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    t1 = std::thread([this] { this->threadFunc(); });
    t1.detach();

}

/////////////////////////

void MyClass::threadFunc()
{
    ///do stuff.. update member variables etc.
}
```

Comment: There are too many avenues for the calling code to cause problems that it's really impossible to answer this question.

Comment: When you start a thread performing a function, all of the local variables in that function will be thread local (ie each thread has its own copy). If the thread is referencing class variables, if one class has multiple running threads than the class variables are common between those threads and you'll need the appropriate mutexes/semaphores/synchronization to ensure multiple threads aren't stepping on each other.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that is the case. I'm trying to understand how it actually works deep down. When main() is called, it sets up the main() stack frame, then on creation of the object and creating different threads and calling different functions, the stack must grow with different stack frames. How can they access the same variables? So the member variables are like global variables in this case.

Comment: Are you asking how to share data between threads?  It's very unclear what you are actually asking.  It seems, to me at least, that you are asking why these variables are being shared when they should not be.  That cannot be told from the code you have shared so far.

Comment: @Engineer999 each thread calls a function which gets added to that threads stack, all local variables to that function exist on that threads stack and are independent. All class members of the object exist on the stack that created the object and have a distinct memory location. All of the threads are in the same virtual address space, and can reference that location (despite it being a part of another stack). This is why when you pass a local variable to a function via reference, it still works even though the variable exists in a different frame on that stack.

Comment: Thanks RyanP. Good explanation

Answer (score 3):

> I've read that different threads share the same memory segments apart
>   from the stack.

This is not entirely accurate. Threads share the same address space as opposed to being sand-boxed like processes are.

The stack is just some memory in your application that has been specifically reserved and is used to hold things such as function parameters, local variables, and other function-related information.

Every thread has it's own stack. This means that when a particular thread is executing, it will use it's own specific stack to avoid trampling over other threads which might be idle or executing simultaneously in a multi-core system.

Remember that these *stacks* are all still inside **the same address space** which means that any thread can access the contents of another threads' stack.

A simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void Foo(int& i)
{
    // if thread t is executing this function then j will sit inside thread t's stack
    // if we call this function from the main thread then j will sit inside the main stack
    int j = 456;

    i++; // we can see i because threads share the same address space
}

int main()
{
    int i = 123; // this will sit inside the main threads' stack

    std::thread t(std::bind(&Foo, std::ref(i))); // we pass the address of i to our thread
    t.join();

    std::cout << i << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

An illustration:

[image]>

As you can see, each thread has its own stack (which is just some part of the processes' memory) which lives inside the same address space.

Comment: Awesome. Just what I was looking for . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
MyClass c1;
MyClass c2;
```

then there will be two instances of MyClass, c1 and c2, each with its own members. The thread started during construction of c1 will have access to c1's members only and the thread started in c2 will have access to c2's members only.

If you are talking about several threads within one class (not obvious from your code), then each thread has a copy of `this` which is just a pointer to your MyClass object. New (local) variables will be allocated on the thread's stack and will be visible only for the thread which creates them.

Comment: This does _nothing_ to answer the question that was actually asked.

Comment: The constructor return type was a typo. Sorry. Yes , I understand that. 2 different objects will have different copies of member variables, but in my case, I don't want that. I am just curious as to what is going on in memory

Comment: @mah for me it is not obvious that what I wrote is not answering OPs question, but I added information which might be what he is looking for.

Comment: @alex you might want to re-read his question. It's pretty clear that he's talking about a single object with multiple threads -- spelled out quite plainly in the top of his second paragraph. (In addition, the OP commented here regarding your answer.) He's trying to understand why the threads are accessing member variables of the same object rather than copies on different stacks -- something which would never be questioned if he were dealing with separate objects to begin with.

Comment: @mah I have been misled by the provided code which creates exactly one thread per instance of MyClass.

Comment: @alex even with creation of one thread, there's still the main thread that perofrmed the creation -- so there are at least two threads that can access the object ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I've read that different threads share the same memory segments apart from the stack. [...] If every thread gets its own stack, why doesn't each thread get a copy of the member variables rather than access to the same variable.

Hmm... the short answer is, that's the purpose for which threads were designed: multiple threads of execution, all accessing the same data. Then you have threading primitives - like mutexes - to make sure that they don't step on each others' toes, so to speak - that you don't have concurrent writes, for example.

Thus in the default case, threads share objects, and you have to do extra work to synchronize accesses. If you want threads to each have copies of objects... then you can instead write the code to give each thread a copy of the object, instead of the same object. Or, you may consider using processes (e.g. via `fork()`) instead of threads.